# Tensorflow Object detection: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Tensor'

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api

I am trying to follow edge electronics object detection method using tensorflow 1.15

First of all, I was getting this warning like this:-

Detection
Load an object detection model:

1
model_name = 'ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_11_17'
2
detection_model = load_model(model_name)
INFO:tensorflow:Saver not created because there are no variables in the graph to restore

And ended up with this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLAUv.png)

Full code : https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/colab_tutorials/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb

Comment: The error might be because the image is not being read properly. Check the image path once.

Comment: Please provide some code that shows where this error is coming from.

Comment: Hello sir, i am using official tensorflow object detection link provided in body,

Comment: @will. evo please go through it and help me, Here is the code...

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YPbK2DXRmVO9GfTvvHVuv87ckvFnEChd/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Without a minimum running example it is hard to identify the problem, but just on the error trace it seems like the problem is that output_dict has tensors in it and python's built in int() function doesn't know how to deal with tensorflow tensors. I can reproduce the problem like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

test = tf.convert_to_tensor(1)
int(test)
```

Your solution might just be to break out the part that pops a value from the dictionary and then convert that from a tensor to a numpy array and then deal with getting it down to an int.